# ADAL - AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String

Tags: xamarin, adal

I used ADAL with ADFS for authenticating web api calls within Xamarin and is experiencing an issue when repeating the authentication process, it appears to be having issue with getting token from the in-memory cache.

Interestingly, I have another demo app which does the same thing and doesn't have the same issue...

The code used is as below, if anyone can shield some lights on how to debug it further it will be much appreciated.

```
try
{
  AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);

  try
  {
     ar = ac.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resourceURI, clientID).Result;
  }
  catch (AggregateException exc)
  {
      //do nothing?
  }

  if (ar == null)
  {
     ar = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceURI, clientID, new Uri(clientReturnURI), parent);
  }
  **catch (Exception ex)**  //always been hit
  {
```

> 2016-08-14 22:54:46.075 TimeSheetiOS[70494:1224472] 8/15/2016 5:54:46
>   AM: c7b85581-cef2-492c-86ee-5686a5d4de67 - TokenCache.cs: Looking up
>   cache for a token... 2016-08-14 22:54:46.076
>   TimeSheetiOS[70494:1224472] 8/15/2016 5:54:46 AM:
>   c7b85581-cef2-492c-86ee-5686a5d4de67 - TokenCache.cs: An item matching
>   the requested resource was found in the cache 2016-08-14 22:54:46.076
>   TimeSheetiOS[70494:1224472] 8/15/2016 5:54:46 AM:
>   c7b85581-cef2-492c-86ee-5686a5d4de67 - TokenCache.cs: 29.0067555833333
>   minutes left until token in cache expires 2016-08-14 22:54:46.077
>   TimeSheetiOS[70494:1224472] 8/15/2016 5:54:46 AM:
>   c7b85581-cef2-492c-86ee-5686a5d4de67 - TokenCache.cs: A matching item
>   (access token or refresh token or both) was found in the cache
>   2016-08-14 22:54:46.082 TimeSheetiOS[70494:1224472] 8/15/2016 5:54:46
>   AM: c7b85581-cef2-492c-86ee-5686a5d4de67 - AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs:
>   System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance
>   of a String. Parameter name: s   at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes
>   (System.String s) [0x00006] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3539/f37444ae/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/text/encoding.cs:1083
>   at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.CryptographyHelper.CreateSha256Hash
>   (System.String input) [0x0000c] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.LogReturnedToken
>   (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult
>   result) [0x00067] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.PostRunAsync
>   (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult
>   result) [0x

Comment: What version of the library are you using?

Comment: Hi Kanishk, it is  3.12.0.827... thx

Comment: Can you file a github issue? I will make the fix next week.